# Using the ProfileAdminService to Follow a user

Tags: connection, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to use the ProfileAdminService (com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.profiles.ProfileAdminService) to get one user to follow another user.

I can see that you can do it via a put to /profiles/admin/atom/following.do but I was hoping to just use service.

I've investigated the FollowService but this only (at least that i can see) allows the current authenticated user to follow someone, but I want to be able to get any user to follow someone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature was not implemented in the IBM Social Business Toolkit SDK 
you can look at the Code for [ProfileAdminService](https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/blob/0f7237b6ff22fed631bde9e4e16ed9744506694c/sdk/com.ibm.sbt.core/src/main/java/com/ibm/sbt/services/client/connections/profiles/ProfileAdminService.java) and you'll see the methods do not include establishing a following relationship.

You need to use the REST API - http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+5.0+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Following_a_person_using_the_Administration_API_ic50&content=apicontent

with the specified body. You need to craft the URL properly in order to get the feature to work via the REST API

Comment: Thanks I thought this was going to be the case.